# Why is the result different?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm training a model about regression problem. the "x" size = (50), sz = 10, weights size is (1,10). After trying this two method to resize x, I get the same matrix of x.

```
a = x.view(50, -1)
b = x.expand(sz, len(x)).t()
print(a*weight == b*weight)
result: True
```

But why I get different loss figure?

Comment: Can you try switching your activation function to a linear function (Eg: no activation) and see if the loss difference persists?

Answer (score 1):

This is called automatic broadcasting, it corresponds to arguments of an operator being automatically expanded to be of equal dimension sizes. That can only happen if (a) the operator supports it *and* (b) the tensors are "broadcastable" ([ref](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#general-semantics)):

> - Each tensor has at least one dimension.
> - When iterating over the dimension sizes, starting at the trailing dimension, the dimension sizes must either be equal, one of them is 1, or one of them does not exist.

In the first case `a` is shaped `(50,1)` while weight is `(1,10)` so the expanded shapes will be `(50,1*10)` and `(1*50,10)` and the operation results in a shape of `(50,10)`. In the second case you have `(50,10)` and `(1,10)`, so the 2nd tensor expands `dim=0` to to `50` resulting in the same shape.

See the [NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for details on broadcasting behaviors.

Comment: So in your opinion, these two case is same right? Why I get different loss graph?

Comment: Yes, the two cases have the same behaviors and the gradients will be the same.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe there are some points I didn't notice.